# Physical interpretation of hadron distribution amplitudes

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, non-perturbative, partons, hadronization

A parton fragmentation function can be interpreted as the probability that a final state hadron originated from that particular hadron.

A parton distribution function can be interpreted as the probability some parton with momentum $xP$ ($x \in (0, 1)$ and $P$ is the hadron momentum) lies within that hadron.

So what exactly is the physical interpretation of a hadron distribution amplitude. I know it is related to exclusive processes. But how would I go about explaining what a hadron distribution amplitude is to a 5-year-old (or me for that matter)?

Comment: Reading the introduction of this thesis which deals with hadron distribution amplitudes ( and parton distributions)  you will see that it is not something  five year old could understand, https://d-nb.info/1163109177/34 . The tern "amplitude" it self needs quantum mechanics mathematics.

Comment: @annav
The "explain like I'm five" is just a term of expression but I see your point. The Thesis is very thorough but perhaps could use a bit more of an explanation. The phrase "interpreted as light-cone wave-functions integrated over transverse quark momenta" is true based off of the operator definition of the DA. However it does not help provide me some intuition on what it means. 

Should I interpret it as "the quark contribution to the wave-function of the hadron?"

Comment: One would have to read and understand the thesis, which is beyond me. I would interpret the statement that " a hadronic wavefunction would have to carry over the effects of parton wave functions"

Comment: The thesis is great in terms of how computing moments of the distribution amplitude on the lattice. The thesis briefly goes over the phenomenological importance of distribution amplitudes, i.e. knowing the likelihood of something like a meson being produced in a semi-inclusive process. 
The thesis however does not really go into any kind of physical interpretation of what the distribution amplitude matrix element is.
Could you elaborate on "a hadronic wave function would have to carry over the effects of parton wave functions"? What does this have to do with non-local quark bilinears?

Comment: only in hand waving terms . two different theories can fit the same data , but then there should be an overlap.For example, temperature is a variable in thermodynamics, and it has been shown that it connects with the average kinetic energy of the particles. In analogous way the hadronic wave function would have to include averages or projections or...of the partons on which the hadron arises.

Comment: Maybe this is a good way of thinking about it. In light-cone quantization, the non-local quark bilinear can be thought of as some sort of quark number density. Hadron states are presumably eigenstates of the QCD Hamiltonian. Whether the non-local quark bilinear operator changes the state of the hadron state rests on whether that operator commutes with the QCD Hamiltonian (not sure, will have to derive it myself at some point). If so we are left some scalar density times the projection between the hadron state vector and the vacuum, whatever that means.

Comment: Actually because both the hadron state vector and the vacuum are energy eigenstates of the QCD Hamiltonion, the non-local quark bilinear must *not* commute with the Hamiltonion.

I understand thinking about describing the overlap between hadrons and quarks/gluons as "two-different-theories". I am coming at it from the approach that hadrons _can_ be written down in terms of some wierd combo of quark/gluon fields acting on the vacuum. How the DA and this operator relate is one another is somehow what the DA is trying to convey I think, but I am not sure how.